# NUXT (SSR Mode) connect Lavarel Pusher Socket

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to connect the Laravel Pucher Socket to NUTX.js ( SSR Mode) Application.
Above code add-in socket socketio.js plugins file. this code not working.
Anyone tell me what's wrong.
How to connect Socket in NUXT SSR mode.

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
import config from "../config/config.global";



export default async ({ store, $axios }) => {
  const port = 6001;

  window.io = require("socket.io-client");
  window.Pusher = require("pusher-js");
  
  console.log(typeof io, "socketIO");
  if (typeof io !== "undefined") {
    // connect to web socket
    try {
      window.Echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: "pusher",
        key: config.secretKey, 
        wsHost: config.socketUrl,
        wsPort: port,
        disableStats: true,
        auth: {
          headers: config.header
        }
      });
      console.log("connect to socket");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }

  function listenStock({ channelName, eventName }, callback) {
    console.log("callback",callback);
    window.Echo.channel(channelName).listen(eventName, callback);
  }
  // Get user Balance Socket
  listenStock(
    {
      channelName: `BalanceUpdateEvent.${store.getters.GetUserUUID}`,
      eventName: "BalanceUpdateEvent"
    },
    ({ data }) => {
      try {      
        console.log(data,"Data");
      } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
      }
    }
  );


};
```

Answer (score 2):

In Nuxt have two Mode SPA and SSR.

1. SPA run only client side
2. SSR run Client and Server Side.

So i created repositories about laravel echo socket pusher service connect to NUXT Mode.

NUXT (SSR Mode):
https://github.com/mankarsandesh/nuxt-socket-laravel-echo-SSR

NUXT (SPA Mode)
https://github.com/mankarsandesh/nuxt-socket-laravel-echo-SPA

Comment: Nice explanation.